# apt cannot verify signatures, does not update, neither does it fetch sources

Tags: debian, apt

I run Debian on a desktop computer. Because os some faulty cable, access to HD failed a couple of times, and this left my `/var` filesystem somewhat corrupted. It is a btrfs filesystem. So, I copied my whole system to another HD, but still there are problems! And I'm not sure they're all related to the filesystem corruption issue.

```
sudo aptitude update
Get: 1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease [209 kB]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
  Unknown error executing apt-key
Fetched 209 kB in 2s (95.9 kB/s)

Current status: 0 (-479) upgradable, 0 (-11) new.
W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease: Unknown error executing apt-key
E: The repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease' is not signed.
```

Strange. `apt-get update` will equally fail. So I did some more testing:

```
sudo apt-get source hello
Reading package lists... Done
Need to get 733 kB of source archives.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  hello
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
```

So `apt-get` will refuse to fetch sources since it believes it won't be able to check signatures. Interesting. Because `apt-get install <whatever-package>` works -- except that it will complain about signature checking:

```
sudo apt-get install hello
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hello
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 479 not upgraded.
Need to get 55.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 545 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  hello
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 hello amd64 2.10-1 [55.7 kB]
Fetched 55.7 kB in 0s (74.9 kB/s)
Retrieving bug reports... Done
Parsing Found/Fixed information... Done
Selecting previously unselected package hello.
(Reading database ... 851110 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../hello_2.10-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking hello (2.10-1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-8) ...
Setting up hello (2.10-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

So, I have ran

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get --reinstall install apt debian-keyring
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt debian-keyring
```

but the problem persists.

And I finally found this problem:

```
sudo apt-key net-update
gpg: relocation error: gpg: symbol gcry_sexp_extract_param, version GCRYPT_1.6 not defined in file libgcrypt.so.20 with link time reference
```

But...

```
ldd `which apt-key`
        not a dynamic executable
```

The bug report pages for [`apt`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=apt;dist=unstable), [`debian-keyring`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=debian-keyring;dist=unstable), [`libgcrypt20`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=libgcrypt20;dist=unstable) do not show anything that seems to be related to this (unless I missed something, of course!)

The Debian version is sid; and my `sources.list` are these:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable main non-free contrib
```

Also, the version of `apt` is `1.3~rc2`, the same that I have on another computer which is running fine.

I wonder if there is anything else I could investigate before actually deciding to reinstall the system from scratch (I have over 15 long years of `/etc` fiddling, and even if I copy `/etc` over to the new installation, I am afraid it wouldn't be as smooth as it seems!)

Comment: Was there more than /var on the failed disk? It sounds like you also have a corrupt /usr. And with that a restore from backup or reinstall is the safest solution.

Comment: @zhenech You are right. I just checked, and it seems that `libgcrypt.so.20` was bad. I moved `/usr` to a new filesystem and it works now! Thank you! (If you post your comment as an answer, I'll be able to accept it)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
apt-get install gnupg libgcrypt20 -o AllowUnauthenticated=true
```

Or better to make a full dist-upgrade recently when you using a rolling distro. If you have still problems then you have to fill the bugreport yourself for the broken fresh packages. The sid release is for collecting bugreports from many users.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, even reinstalling `libgcrypt20` didn't help, because `/usr` was also bad. So I moved `/usr` to a new filesystem, reinstalled `libgcrypt20` and now everything works.

Answer (score -1):

I was just getting this error.  Don't ask me why, but it was fixed by running:

```
$ sudo chmod +r /usr/bin/*
```